# Ubuntu host can't ping guest virtual box Windows 10

Tags: networking, virtualbox, windows-10, virtualbox-networking

I have the following components:

- Host: Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS.
- Guest: Virtual Box with Windows 10.

In Virtual box, I already selected "`Bridged Adapter`" for this Windows VM, I also changed static IP of this VM so that it could match to my host Ubuntu.

But I still can't ping from my Ubuntu host to Windows VM. However, Windows VM can ping Ubuntu host, and I have a shared folder between them, it works.

What else can I do so my host Ubuntu can ping my Windows VM? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it's turned out, there was a firewall on my guest machine. After I deactivated it, I can ping to my guest VM. Everything works as expected

Comment: Not working for me. I have disabled the guest (Win10) firewall altogether but host (18.04) still can't ping it.

Comment: I just tested by turning off/on Firewall on my guest Windows, and it still works for me. My host is still 16.04 though, maybe something different with 18.04

Comment: Yes, this works perfectly in my case. I was trying to ping from host Ubuntu Mate 19.04 to guest Windows Server 2019 LTSC in VMware Workstation Pro, and it was not going through. Though instead of disabling Server 2019 firewall completely, I created a custom rule to allow IPs from my lan. Thanks.